# laravel 5.8 echoing out without searching anything

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have small issue that search result showing up even though without searching keys. here's snippet.
this is view:

```
<form action="/search" method="GET">
<div class="form-group search-location">
    <input type="text" name="cityKey" id="cityKey" value="{{ request()->input('cityKey') }}"
           class="form-control" >

</div>
<div class="form-group search-info">

    <input type="text" name="key" id="key" value="{{ request()->input('key') }}"
           class="form-control" >

</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary search-btn"><i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    <span>search</span></button>
```

Here's controller:

```
public function search(Request $request){
    $cityKey = $request->cityKey;
    $key = $request->key;


    $doctors = Doctor_list::where('speciality_title', 'LIKE', '%' . $key . '%')->
    where('location', 'LIKE', '%' . $cityKey . '%')->
    orWhere('doctors_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $key . '%')->
    where('location', 'LIKE', '%' . $cityKey . '%')->
    orWhere('speciality_type', 'LIKE', '%' . $key . '%')->
    where('location', 'LIKE', '%' . $cityKey . '%');
```

//complete the query and terminate it with paginate or ->get()
        $doctors = $doctors->get();

```
    return view('search', compact('doctors'));


}
```

Comment: what exactly you want. explain a little bit

Comment: you can put validation to check whether `key` and `cityKey` is not null..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is easy just don't pass the $doctors variable to view(or better say that pass and empty var) and in view detect its empty and say no results for searching. here's the code:

```
public function search(Request $request){
    $cityKey = $request->cityKey;
    $key = $request->key;

    if (filled($cityKey) && filled($key)) {
        $doctors = Doctor_list::where('speciality_title', 'LIKE', '%' . $key . '%')->
        where('location', 'LIKE', '%' . $cityKey . '%')->
        orWhere('doctors_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $key . '%')->
        where('location', 'LIKE', '%' . $cityKey . '%')->
        orWhere('speciality_type', 'LIKE', '%' . $key . '%')->
        where('location', 'LIKE', '%' . $cityKey . '%')->
        get();
    }
    return view('search', [
        'doctors' => $doctors ?? []
    ]);
}
```

with this you dont even query to database. and filled is a laravel helper function returns whether the given value is not "blank" here the link: https://laravel.com/docs/helpers#method-filled